# Angular - Type '"desc"' is not assignable to type 'null'

Tags: angular

In Angular-12, I am trying to sort a table using:

```
sortData = {        //Current Sort Data
  "col" : null,
  "order" : null
}

sort(col: any){
  if(this.sortData.order=="asc" && this.sortData.col==col){
    this.sortData.order = "desc"
  } else if(this.sortData.order=="desc" && this.sortData.col==col){
    this.sortData.order = null;
    col = null;
  } else {
    this.sortData.order = "asc"
  }
  this.sortData.col = col;
  this.ngOnInit();
}
```

I got this error:

> Type '"desc"' is not assignable to type 'null'.

With this line highlighted:

> this.sortData.order = "desc"

> this.sortData.order = "asc"

How do I sort this out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
sortData : { col: null | string, order: null | string} = {        //Current Sort Data
  "col" : null,
  "order" : null
}
```

This will pass the `null` type check. Also, it seems the code is fine and should not generate any errors if it is please add more code to the question and/or debugging details.

Note: You should understand the `lifecycle` methods are being called implicitly by angular. You shouldn't do that, if you want to call the logic of `onInit` multiple times, try separating it in a new function.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to define a class and declare the type of your object as that class:

```
export class SortDataModel {
  col: any;          \\ your desired type: string, number,...
  order: any;        \\ your desired type: string, number,...
}
```

Then define your variable:

```
public sortData: SortDataModel = {
  col: null,
  order: null
}
```

Another way is to define your variable type as `any` to bypass the type error. but I don't recommend it myself:

```
public sortData: any = {
  col: null,
  order: null
}
```

Comment: Why not use interface instead?

Comment: that is another way to achieve the goal indeed. I just prefer classes so I can create instances of them with `new` with default values I want.

Comment: I see! I just thought it was a bit unusual from other projects I've seen. I usually just create a function that creates an object of that type of I want to create a default initiator.